# On the symmetric group $\mathrm{S}_n$, prove that $\operatorname{sign}\left(\mathrm{S}_n\right) \subseteq\{ \pm 1\}$

Tags: proof-verification, permutations, symmetric-groups

This is exercise 9.6a from Section. *The Rational Numbers* in textbook *Analysis I* by *Amann/Escher*.

> On the symmetric group $\mathrm{S}_n$, define the sign function by $$\operatorname{sign} \sigma := \prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(k)}{j-k}, \qquad \sigma \in \mathrm{S}_{n}$$
>
> Prove that
>
> 1. $\operatorname{sign}\left(\mathrm{S}_n\right) \subseteq\{ \pm 1\}$.
> 2. $\operatorname{sign}(\sigma \circ \tau)=(\operatorname{sign} \sigma)(\operatorname{sign} \tau)$ for $\sigma, \tau \in \mathrm{S}_{n}$.

---

Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains logical gaps/errors?

**My attempt:**

> 1. We have
>
> $$\begin{alignat}{2} |\operatorname{sign} \sigma| &= \left |\prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(k)}{j-k} \right |  &&= \frac{\prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} |\sigma(j)-\sigma(k)|}{\prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n}|j-k|}\\ &= \frac{\prod_{1 \leq j'<k '\leq n} |j' - k'|}{\prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n}|j-k|} &&= 1 \end{alignat}$$
>
> The conclusion then follows.
>
> 2. We have
>
> $$\begin{align}\operatorname{sign} (\sigma \circ \tau) &= \prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{\sigma \circ \tau (j)-\sigma \circ \tau (k)}{j-k} \\ &= \prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{(\sigma \circ \tau (j)-\sigma \circ \tau (k))(\tau(j)-\tau(k))}{(j-k)(\tau(j)-\tau(k))} \\ &= \left (\prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{\sigma \circ \tau (j)-\sigma \circ \tau (k)}{\tau(j)-\tau(k)} \right ) \left ( \prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{\tau(j)-\tau(k)}{j-k} \right ) \\ &= \left (\prod_{1 \leq j'<k' \leq n} \frac{\sigma (j')-\sigma (k')}{j'-k'} \right ) \left ( \prod_{1 \leq j<k \leq n} \frac{\tau(j)-\tau(k)}{j-k} \right ) \\ &= (\operatorname{sign} \sigma) (\operatorname{sign} \tau) \end{align}$$

---

**Update:** On the basis of @Bernard's comment, I added an update to make my proof more rigorous.

In 1., for a pair $(j,k)$ with $j < k$: If $\sigma(j) < \sigma(k)$ then I define $j':= \sigma(j)$ and $k':= \sigma(k)$, otherwise I define $j':= \sigma(k)$ and $k':= \sigma(j)$. In either case, $|\sigma(j)-\sigma(k)| = |j'-k'|$.

Comment: Point 2 is fine for me. For point 1,  how do you know that $\sigma(j)=j'<\sigma(k)=k'$?

Comment: Hi @Bernard, for a pair $(j,k)$ with $j < k$: if $\sigma(j) < \sigma(k)$ then I define $j':= \sigma(j), k':= \sigma(k)$, otherwise I define $j':= \sigma(k), k':= \sigma(j)$. In either case, $|\sigma(j)-\sigma(k)| = |j'-k'|$.

Comment: OK,  but you have to explain that in the proof

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard! I add an update to reflect your suggestion :)